# React-Native: Blank screen on fresh project

Tags: android, react-native

So I just started a new project with react-native. Standard "react-native init" etc as per the official guide.

All was fine until  ran the app on my emulator. All I saw is a blank page. If I create some errors and reload I get the standard error message but when all compiles fine I just get a blank screen.

OS: Win10
RN ver: 0.44.0
RA ver: 16.0.0-alpha.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try a combination of:

1. Close the packager (let it restart at next deploy)
2. Remove the app from emulator/device
3. Build & deploy application again

That's what I do if I am presented with a blank screen.
If it didn't help you, what is the console output if you enable remote debugging?

Comment: tnx. restarting the emulator fixed the issue.

Comment: Restarting the emulator seems a bit drastic, but if it helps :)

Comment: Yeah. It happened again later. Not quite sure what is casing this

Comment: Well, we're all too happy to start with react-native but we seem to forget that it's only on version 0.44. There are a lot of unexplainable bugs to come before it's a finished product :)